# CoreData error while saving: "binding not implemented for this SQLType 7

Tags: iphone, core-data

i am new to Core Data and my model is to complex to describe it here, sorry.

My App fetch many small amounts of data from the web and store it to the core data entities. 
The saving is fine sometimes, but sometimes there is an

```
NSInternalInconsistencyException
```

with this description

`binding not implemented for this SQLType 7`

The Exception raises in the

```
[NSManagedObjectContext save:]
```

method so i cannot go through it using the debugger.

I checked my CoreData model and everything seems fine. I checked all values from the console and non of the required attributes are nil.

Maybe someone has an idee to fix this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out this was a multi-threading issue having to do with locking the persistent store. Funny, it was never an issue on 10.4 or 10.5.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting this error as well.  According to the somewhat dated SQL headers I found in the 10.4 SDK, type 7 is Real.  My model uses the Decimal type quite extensively which probably maps to the SQL Real type.  My best guess is that the SQL routines that bind these types to their statements are broken or incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

my problem get solved when i save changed directly after they were made to the model. Maybe there are some unprocessed changes which overlap some other changes and this produce the error.
According to Apple Docs you should always save changes directly after they are made

> Remember that the managed object
> context acts like a scratch pad (see
> “Managed Objects and  the Managed
> Object Context”). Whatever changes you
> make—whether editing property values
> or adding or deleting whole
> objects—aren’t actually committed to
> the persistent store (file) until you
> save the context. Typically, in an
> iPhone application, you save changes
> as soon as the user has made them.
>
> [CoreData iPhone Tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Articles/04_Adding.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008305-CH106-SW1)

Hope this help you solving your problem as well.

Good Luck ;-)